# Which law defines the AC inducing voltage in the inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

If we connect an inductor without ohmic resistance to the alternating voltage source, voltage should induce in the inductor because of the Faraday's law. Voltage is induced by changing magnetic flux through the inductor which is accomplished by alternating current through it. Therefore, in order for us to find the induced voltage, we need to know what that current is, $I(t)$.

Which law defines this current? If we say, Faraday's law (or Kirchoff's voltage law in the context of the lumped model), we're already assuming that the voltage on the inductor is equal to the source voltage. But, we can't know this prior to knowing what the current, $I(t)$ is, as voltage is induced by changing the current through the inductor. If you ask me, there is a circularity in this reasoning which is often used in textbooks.

I'd highly appreciate your thoughts as I'm confused.

Comment: > *"we're already assuming that the voltage on the inductor is equal to the source voltage. But, we can't know this prior to knowing what the current"* For any two points, including terminals of inductor, there is only one value of voltage (difference of the Coulomb-gauge electric potential). It need not be the same value as voltage of the voltage source when it is not connected, but when it is connected to those terminals, there is only one voltage between those two points. So then voltage on inductor is the same as voltage of the source.

Answer (score 1):

Faraday's law relates the inductor voltage to the magnetic flux through it (or equivalently, the current). That's it. You could read it as "time-varying current causes voltage", but equally well as "voltage causes change in current". In truth, Faraday's law indicates no causality. Whether the inductor is connected to a voltage source or a current source, the relation between voltage and current is the same. Note also that you can write Faraday's law as an explicit equation for the current:
$$I(t) = I(t_0) + \frac 1 L \int\limits_{t_0}^tV(\tau)d\tau.$$

Maybe an ideal resistor is a helpful analogy. Does the current you push through a resistor result in a potential difference across it? Or does the potential difference applied across the resistor result in current flow? It doesn't matter, the relation between the voltage and current is Ohm's law.

Comment: Yes, my question implies causality exists and is unidirectional (changing current causes voltage). After some discussion, I learned that Faraday's law isn't really one of causality.  Experiments relate current and voltage on the inductor by the Faraday's law which is simply how inductors act, it's a fundamental law of nature. We can interpret them that inductors resist current changes (bigger the inductance smaller the current change for a given voltage).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you a concerned about the transient behaviour of a circuit which contains an inductor and an alternating voltage source.

Once the transients have died down then the steady state voltage and current graphs look something like this with the voltage leading the current by $90^\circ$.

[image]

Now consider the alternating voltage source, the inductor and an open switch all in series.
The current passing through the inductor is zero.

The switch is closed.

All is fine if the switch is closed at time t1 or time t3 when the voltage is at a maximum/minimum as the current through the inductor being zero is as it will be in steady state.

However, it is more likely that the switch will be closed at a time like t2 when the voltage is not at a maximum or a minimum and to be in steady state the current through the inductor has to become a finite value instantaneously.
This is physically impossible.

Thus there must be a transition period starting with the voltage at time t2 and the current through the inductor being zero to a final state when the current and voltage are as shown in the graphs above.

This is where one must change the unrealistic model of just having a ideal voltage source, an ideal inductor and no resistance in the circuit.

Just adding series resistance to the circuit will not help because with zero initial current there is no voltage across the resistor.

A more realistic circuit is one which contains some resistance and stray/parasitic capacitance.
Once the effect of these circuit elements are evaluated their values can be changed to see for how long the transient behaviour exists.
In many cases the transients die away in less than a period of the alternating voltage supply and thus are usually not noticed.

Comment: Why the need for capacitance? At t=0 the coil is just a piece of wire, and the current is given by V/R, or at least it tries to reach that value instantly. But as the surface charge on the conductors (coil included) tries to assume the configuration to allow that value of current, the current 'locally forming' in the circuit will create a changing magnetic field that will induce an electric field that opposes that change.

Comment: *At t=0 the coil is just a piece of wire, and the current is given by V/R* is an instantaneous change with the piece of wire having inductance?

Comment: Inductance is a name we place on the portion of space where the phenomena of induction happens, it's not a property of the wire. The current change tries to be instantaneous, but the best that can be done is limited by how fast the charge can redistribute itself to respond to the new condition following the closure of the switch (or completing the circuit in some way). That happens with relaxation times, which are of the order of eps/sigma . But as soon as the current starts to flow, it create the changing flux that changes the electric field, that alters the surface charge distr. & curr. I.

Comment: I am sorry my wording was poor. I was trying to explain that nothing happens instantaneously and that given the applied voltage is a certain value an inductor can "react" to that voltage by a change of current through it.  The problem arises because there is a mismatch between the steady state current at a given supply voltage and the current being zero at that given supply voltage when the switch is closed. In the initial stages the current vs supply voltage graph will not be the same as when steady state is reached.

Comment: The transition cannot be explained by just having an ideal inductor connected to an ideal voltage supply.